# PGFPlots Line Plot at constant x

Tags: pgfplots, plot, 3d

In [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272874/artificial-line-in-pgfplots-3d-parametric-plots) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102546/3d-line-plot-in-pgfplots) question, we learned how to draw real line plots in 3D axes in PGFPlots by supplying `samples y=1` (`samples y=0` seems to work as well) or `y domain=0:0` to get rid of meshes/matrices.

However, I could not get it to work for the 'perpendicular' direction, when we try to plot a line plot in the X-Y-plane (where `x=const.`, as opposed to the `X-Z`-plane (where `y=const.`). The result was not a line plot, but a 'fake' 3D plot, with the colormap still intact:

```
%!TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xlabel={x},
            ylabel={y},
            zlabel={z},
            domain=0:5*360,
            y domain=0:5*360,
            surf
            ]
            % These work:
            \addplot3[ultra thick, samples y=1] ({x}, {0}, {cos(x)});
            \addplot3[ultra thick, samples y=1] ({x}, {0}, {cos(x)+4});

            % This is in analogy to above, but does not work
            % (Package pgfplots Warning: the current plot has no coordinates (or all have been filtered away)). 
            \addplot3[ultra thick, samples=1] ({5*360}, {y}, {cos(y)+2});

            % These work, but don't give a line plot:
            \addplot3[ultra thick, domain=5*360:5*360] ({x}, {y}, {cos(y)+2});
            \addplot3[ultra thick] ({5*360}, {y}, {cos(y)+2});
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

yielding:

[image: broken 3d line plot]

I do not know why `\addplot3[ultra thick, samples=1] ({5*360}, {y}, {cos(y)+2});` does not work.
How can we produce real line plots in the second direction as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is somewhat similar to your own answer but arguably from a different perspective. You are considering parametric plots, in which `x` and `y` are just parameters or placeholders, and not to be confused with the `x` and `y` coordinates. To make this a bit clearer, I rename the parameter `t`. Effectively this is then practically the same as your answer (with `surf` removed and the plots made smooth). I also added a plot that does not go along any of the axes to reiterate the point.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xlabel={$x$},
            ylabel={$y$},
            zlabel={$z$},
            domain=0:5*360,
            y domain=0:5*360,
            samples=101,smooth
            ]
            % These work:
            \addplot3[ultra thick,variable=\t, samples y=0] ({t}, {0}, {cos(t)});
            \addplot3[ultra thick,variable=\t, samples y=0] ({t}, {0}, {cos(t)+4});
            \addplot3[ultra thick,variable=\t, samples y=0] ({5*360}, {t}, {cos(t)+2});
            \addplot3[ultra thick,variable=\t, samples y=0,color=blue] 
            ({900+800*cos(t)}, {900+800*sin(t)}, {cos(12*t)+1});
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was wondering why the line plot elements weren't joined at their ends. Omitting `surf` for those plots solved that, nice. And also yes, parametric plots confuse me a lot when we throw around `x`s and `y`s so much. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

If we swap around the parametric functions we can rely on the working `y samples=0` approach like so:

```
%!TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xlabel={x},
            ylabel={y},
            zlabel={z},
            domain=0:5*360,
            y domain=0:5*360,
            surf
            ]
            % These work:
            \addplot3[ultra thick, samples y=1] ({x}, {0}, {cos(x)});
            \addplot3[ultra thick, samples y=1] ({x}, {0}, {cos(x)+4});

            % Swapping around the parametric functions allows it to work:
            \addplot3[ultra thick, samples y=1] ({5*360}, {x}, {cos(x)+2});
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

yielding:

[image: line plot in 3d]